# Explicacion GitHub Codespaces y Gitpod

Tags: github

Estoy leyendo sobre esto pero soy un poco duro. Que son exactamente y para que me sirven Codespaces y Gitpod para el desarrollo web. Si pueden detallarlo para un novato, se agradece. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué has entendido, y qué no. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.